How do I find out which third party package is using defaultProps in my react app and is the cause of these warnings?
I left my react app project for more than a year and now that I came back to it, I had to deal with a lot of deprecated packages (the project started 3 years ago). I spent a good 2 3 days fixing the deprecations and updating NodeJS from version 15 to 20 + Mongoose and other packages. Including reworking some of the function calls.
Now I'm stuck at these pesky warnings which take half my debugging console (see below). Does anyone know a good approach to deal with these warnings ?
I'm not sure I should manually look inside each file in node_modules (already tried and found more than 1000 occurrance of defaultProps). I'm assuming it's one or 2 packages maybe that need to be either removed or further updated. However, I have no outdated packages anymore after I pulled an ncu -u command.
console.js:288 Warning: lo: Support for defaultProps will be removed from function components in a future major release. Use JavaScript default parameters instead.
at lo (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:57486:15)
at div
at http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:56846:62
at MenuList (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:57763:17)
at ur (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:58527:13)
at div
at http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:56846:62
at Menu (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:57753:17)
at ao (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:57433:15)
at div
at http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:56846:62
at SelectContainer (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:57948:17)
at a (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:59174:8)
at http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:60568:8
at http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:60886:33
at div
at form
at Apartments (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:7121:3)
at ConnectFunction (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:113157:74)
at RenderedRoute (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:65766:5)
at Outlet (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:66381:26)
at RenderedRoute (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:65766:5)
at Outlet (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:66381:26)
at section
at RenderedRoute (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:65766:5)
at Routes (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:66468:5)
at Router (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:66402:15)
at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:64343:5)
at Provider (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:113307:3)
at App (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:217:51)

console.js:288 Warning: No: Support for defaultProps will be removed from function components in a future major release. Use JavaScript default parameters instead.
at No (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:57597:15)
at div
at http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:56846:62
at IndicatorsContainer (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:57717:17)
at div
at http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:56846:62
at Control (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:57662:17)
at div
at http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:56846:62
at SelectContainer (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:57948:17)
at a (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:59174:8)
at http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:60568:8
at http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:60886:33
at div
at form
at Apartments (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:7121:3)
at ConnectFunction (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:113157:74)
at RenderedRoute (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:65766:5)
at Outlet (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:66381:26)
at RenderedRoute (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:65766:5)
at Outlet (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:66381:26)
at section
at RenderedRoute (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:65766:5)
at Routes (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:66468:5)
at Router (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:66402:15)
at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:64343:5)
at Provider (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:113307:3)
at App (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:217:51)
console.js:288 Warning: po: Support for defaultProps will be removed from function components in a future major release. Use JavaScript default parameters instead.
at po (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:57497:13)
at div
at http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:56846:62
at MenuList (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:57763:17)
at ur (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:58527:13)
at div
at http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:56846:62
at Menu (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:57753:17)
at ao (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:57433:15)
at div
at http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:56846:62
at SelectContainer (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:57948:17)
at a (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:59174:8)
at http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:60568:8
at http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:60886:33
at div
at form
at Apartments (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:7121:3)
at ConnectFunction (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:113157:74)
at RenderedRoute (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:65766:5)
at Outlet (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:66381:26)
at RenderedRoute (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:65766:5)
at Outlet (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:66381:26)
at section
at RenderedRoute (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:65766:5)
at Routes (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:66468:5)
at Router (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:66402:15)
at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:64343:5)
at Provider (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:113307:3)
at App (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:217:51)

